# Get Configurable Child Image

Tags: magento2

I have a custom module setup where child images are added to cart instead of their configurable parents. This works great.
I'm now looking to add the child images to Cart, Minicart and Order Summary.
I'm using this to get the image url and send it to the frontend:

```
$imageUrl = $this->imageHelper->init($_product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();
```

This works for simple products.
However, when I have two simple products from a configurable added to the cart, it shows the same image for both and not their own.
I am retrieving the product id as such:

```
  $_product = $this->productModel->load($productId);  
  $product = $_product->getId();
```

And I can see the product ID is correct. I think perhaps I need to retrieve the item ID rather than product ID but I'm unsure.

Note that the Configurable Product Image setting in Stores > Settings Configuration > Sales > Checkout makes no difference here as I'm overriding that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I thought that this is default Magento feature :?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have product model then you can call `$product->getThumbnail()` to the image of the product. Note that it would not give the full path to the image. You can get full path using

```
$fullImageUrl = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$product->getThumbnail()
```

**EDIT**

If you are working with helpers then all helpers already extend `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper` so you can use following code instead

```
$fullImageUrl = parent::_getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$product->getThumbnail()
```

Comment: Unfortunately retrieving via $block doesn't work here as it's a custom helper function I'm writing.

Comment: You can use `parent::_getUrl` instead, check edit.

Comment: I get an output of "no_selection" for this. Thumbnail is set on the parent product.
Image path it gives is pub/media/catalog/no_selection

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a configuration for this, go to

**Admin**->**Stores**->**Configuration**->**Sales**->**Checkout**->**Shopping Cart**

Find **Configurable Product Image** and change it to **Product Thumbnail Itself**

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: As I said in my original post, this setting is irrelevant as I'm overriding that with the module.